# Un présent dans un récit au passé simple : explication (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: untagged

> (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)
> Ici, le silence devint tel, qu’on eût entendu un cloporte grimper au cadre
> de la glace. L’orateur vient à son bureau. Il y prit une feuille de papier qui
> s’y étalait au sein de multiples paperasses, l’éleva jusqu’à ses yeux et lut :
> « Le garde des Sceaux, ministre de la Justice ;

Les temps de la narration sont le passé simple, le passé composé, et le présent.

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_de_narration))
>
> Le temps de narration est le temps principal d’un récit en français : passé simple, passé composé ou présent. Il est employé pour les évènements considérés comme principaux, qui constituent la trame de l’histoire et y apparaissent dans l’ordre selon lequel ils se sont réellement produits. Le point de référence temporelle se déplace d’évènement principal en évènement principal au fur et à mesure de la narration, c’est pourquoi on dit que ces évènements font avancer le récit. Les autres évènements et situations, qui constituent le « décor », sont indiqués chacun dans un temps qui met en évidence leur relation temporelle (simultanéité-antériorité-postériorité) avec l’évènement principal les précédant (plus rarement : les suivant) immédiatement.
>
> La plupart des récits ont comme temps de narration le passé simple (seulement à l’écrit) ou le passé composé (écrit et oral) ; le passé antérieur, variante du passé simple, peut notamment apparaître dans des subordonnées temporelles. Certains récits ont comme temps de narration le présent. Si le temps de narration est un temps du passé, les temps du décor sont l’imparfait, le plus-que-parfait et le conditionnel[réf. nécessaire] (généralement présent, plus rarement passé). S’il s’agit du présent, les temps du décor sont le présent, l'imparfait, le passé composé et le futur, éventuellement le futur antérieur.

Comment explique-t-on l'insertion du présent dans le texte de Courteline alors que le temps de la narration est le passé simple (« devint », « vient », « prit », « lut ») ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147262/discussion-on-question-by-lph-un-present-dans-un-recit-au-passe-simple-explica); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

L'explication est la même que dans d'autres passages de Courteline: Courteline essaie de donner un style vivant, à mi-chemin du théâtre et de la prose traditionelle, à son récit, et ce présent rend l'action plus immédiate. Elle *réveille* le lecteur en quelque sorte, qui aurait pu *s'endormir* dans une narration *monochrone* et conventionnelle au passé.

Cette petite phrase au présent détonne, et elle force le lecteur à se replonger dans l'action, à *voir* l'action en temps réel devant ses yeux plutôt que de rester dans une narration figée dans le passé. Le récit acquiert un aspect plus *visuel* à travers ce présent, on *voit* le protagoniste venir à son bureau bien mieux que si le récit était resté au passé simple.

Courteline semble être friant de ce genre de *cassure* dynamique dans le flot de la narration, de changement de rythme, de temps, ou de point de vue, et c'est là bien sûr sa prérogative d'auteur.